# How To Add Memory?

Tags: theme-development

I just installed wordpress on WAMP localhost win8. However at the very end of the Wordpress installation a little box popped up saying something about there being no disk space, which I regret not screenshotting before hitting OK. I cannot upload media of any kind as there is no space, and the preview of Wordpress available doesn't appear anything like the tutorial said it would.

Tutorial said this:
[image]
Actually looks like this:
[image]

I have tried messing with `php.ini` max file size to no avail.

In case you are wondering I am following this tutorial: http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/web-development-tutorials/using-xampp-for-local-wordpress-theme-development/

Comment: That tutorial is almost 5 years old. Try [something newer](http://wpkrauts.com/2014/wordpress-in-a-nutshell-wt-nmp/).

Comment: @toscho how old is the oldest you would use?

Comment: Not sure, it has been a long time since I needed that kind of a tutorial. :) Make it one year.